How to show that the increment operation for natural numbers is well defined?
Let $a,b$ be natural numbers and $++$ be an increment operation. Based on Peano axioms alone, how to show that if $a=b$, then $a++ = b++$?
Do note that the book I am reading (Real Analysis by Terrence Tao) does not mention that the increment operator is a function (actually at this stage the functions are not even defined yet). I am aware of this post, but it doesn't seem to answer the question, rather than just saying that this is "self-explanatory".
So how would we show it? I'd thought trying induction, but it didn't lead me anywhere.

The accepted answer to the post you linked is the standard answer, and it is definitely not saying that it's self-explanatory. If you have a concern about the answer there, could you edit your post to explain your concern? If your concern is just that functions hadn't been officially set up yet, then the answer you're looking for may be "the textbook isn't a book on logic/foundations, so has a gap in setup here".

@MarkS. No, the accepted answer is fine, since it assumes that the successor operation is a function. When I was saying "self-explanatory", I was talking about the remaining 2 answers, which only referred to successor as an "operation". So am I understanding it correctly that whatever formulation of Peano axioms, successor operator is always defined to be a function? Wikipedia seems to be doing just that, but Tao's book doesn't, and since his text is supposed to be pretty rigorous one, so I'd thought there might be some other way to prove that the successor operation is well defined.

Background
There are a number of different approaches to logic and the Peano Postulates, which is why this question can be a little tricky to answer without a lot of context, some of which is outside the scope of Tao's text, because it's a text on Analysis, not a text on logic.
In "Analysis I" by Terence Tao, we have the following:

the increment operation...
Axiom 2.2 If $n$ is a natural number, then $n\!+\!\!+$ is also a natural number.

What Tao does not say, is what properties of "operations" and equality he is assuming.
Intuition
I expect that Tao expects you to think about things intuitively to some degree, despite the level of rigor he is introducing you to.
On an intuitive level, since $a=b$, $a$ and $b$ are the same number. You can't do the same operation ($+\!\!+$) to the same number and get a different result. So we must have $a\!+\!\!+=b\!+\!\!+$. I believe this is how you were intended to think about it, based on the exposition and the target audience of the book.
Logic
If this were a more advanced/abstract book that was partly about logic, then a standard logical setup would be chosen which would take care of this issue.
Basically, if you read texts that discuss "first-order logic with equality" or similar, then in a "first-order theory" or similar, you may have certain "function symbols" which you write with function notation, but aren't necessarily to be interpreted as a function between sets, etc.
And then you explicitly have an axiom or similar called "substitution for functions" or "(function) congruence" which say that if $f$ is a function symbol (which takes one input) that's a part of your setup, then "$a=b$ implies $f(a)=f(b)$".
In a context like that, we could declare that, say, $s$ is a function symbol (for successor), and that we follow standard logical rules for equality, then "$a=b$ implies $s(a)=s(b)$". And then we could declare that we'll use a shorthand in writing where $a\!+\!\!+$ means $s(a)$.

The reason why I was confused is because whenever Tao defines all other objects or operations, he always starts with explicitly mentioning the fact that  we should show equality axioms (including substitution axiom) hold. But with natural numbers, for some reason, he decided to just let us "assume" things. And to be honest it would've been really easy to patch things up: he could've just said that operator is a function and mentioned that, although functions/sets are defined in later chapters, the set axioms and function definition is separate from Peanno axioms, so there is no issue
